# less jumps syntax error on 'transition-timing function'

Tags: css, less, transition

I'm just converting a alredy made CSS file into a LESS and would like to know why cant I add transition-timing function in the less stylesheet

the code

```
-webkit-transition-timing function: linear, ease-in;
-moz-transition-timing function: linear, ease-in; 
transition-timing function: linear, ease-in;
```

the error

[image]

the reason?

Comment: try adding a dash - `-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;` instead of `-webkit-transition-timing function: linear, ease-in;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're missing the `-` before function.

2) You can only define one value for `*-transition-timing-function`.

**CSS**

```
transition-timing-function: ease-in;
-o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
```